# How to read input from Shell Session using JSch in Java?

Tags: java, shell, jsch

I am trying to develop a Shell Emulator and using Jsch for the same. I am trying to open a shell session but I am not able to read the input stream from the Shell session. I am using the following code.

```
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        Session session;

        session = jsch.getSession(username, server, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        session.connect(30000);

        Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");

        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();


        int SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] buf=new byte[SIZE];
        while(true)
        {
            buflen=in.read(buf, bufs, buf.length-bufs);
            if(buflen<=0){
                buflen=0;
                throw new IOException("fillBuf");
            }
            System.out.println(buflen);
        }
```

But no output is coming. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a:

```
channel.connect(<timeout>)
```

before reading from the input stream.